# Controller Test Failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, testing, junit

I trying to make some controller tests to test the endpoints of my API

```
@Test
  @WithMockUser(username = "049170303", password = "pass", roles = "EMPLOYEE")
  void getAllLocations_GivenValidRequest_ShouldReturnOk() throws Exception {

when(locationService.listAll()).thenReturn(List.of(LocationResponse.builder()
    .id(UUID.fromString("50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7"))
    .name("Ujsjellsi")
    .location("Prishtine")
    .startDate(LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 21))
    .endDate(LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 2))
    .build()
));
this.mvc.perform(get("/api/locations"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.size()", Matchers.is(1)))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value(UUID.fromString("50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7")))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name").value("Ujsjellsi"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[2].location").value("Prishtine"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[3].startDate").value(LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 21)))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[4].endDate").value(LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 2)));


 }
```

But for some reason its not recognizing my UUID and im getting this error:

```
JSON path "$[0].id" expected:<50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7> but was:<50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7>
Expected :50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7
Actual   :50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7
```

Answer (score 0):

MockMVC by default uses `JsonSmartJsonProvider` to deserialize the response. Your response is not deserialized to your domain object - by default JSON Object will be deserialized to a Map.

In particular, `JsonSmartJsonProvider` will not convert Strings to UUIDs.

You need to compare the actual value you extracted from JSON with a String, not UUID.

```java
andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value("50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7"))
```

The test output is not helpful in your case as textual representation of UUID is not distinguishable from the String used to create it:

```java
var uuid = UUID.fromString("50df6107-840e-4152-a981-d5bad1fc74a7");
System.out.println(uuid);
```

See [Json conversion errors with Spring MockMvc](https://dev.to/piczmar_0/json-conversion-errors-with-spring-mockmvc-2ma1)